# VBA- wanted to click element which has multiple frames

Tags: vba, selenium, internet-explorer, web-scraping, iframe

With the previous question's answer I stepped ahead however still stuck on one point where I wanted to click the element  but it seems it has 2 frames and thats the reason when I am running code its giving error that element not found, please check attachment and below code and advise.

```
Sub activeBexIE_Final()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'On Error Resume Next
Dim Perm_bot As New Selenium.IEDriver         
  
Perm_bot.Get "official link"

Perm_bot.Wait 2000

Perm_bot.FindElementById("logonuidfield").SendKeys "XYZ"
Perm_bot.SendKeys Perm_bot.Keys.Tab
Perm_bot.SendKeys "PQR"
Perm_bot.SendKeys Perm_bot.Keys.Enter
Perm_bot.Wait 40000

Perm_bot.switchToFrame 
Perm_bot.FindElementById("iframe_Roundtrip_9223372036563636042")
Perm_bot.FindElementById("BUTTON_OPEN_SAVE_btn1_acButton").SendKeys 
Perm_bot.Keys.Enter
Perm_bot.Wait 30000' *till here I am sucessful- Opening Url-login-click on 
"Open" option*

*'from here I am unable to move further, pls check attachment"select 
layout" like how I wanted to select and also check the attachment "frame" 
and "element" which is having the HTML details, not sure if this particular 
element has 2 element, if yes then how I should write the script and after 
this I wanted to do  tab 7 times and then enter, kindly help for further 
script, thanks in advance

'Perm_bot.switchToFrame Perm_bot.FindElementById("urPopupOuter0")

Perm_bot.switchToFrame Perm_bot.FindElementById("urPopupInner0")

Perm_bot.FindElementById("LOAD_state_tigen4_tlv1_list_unid6_tv").Click

SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    
Perm_bot.Wait 10000
  
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
    'perm_dot.Quit
'Set perm_dot = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

[Select Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L812S.png)
[Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo6S5.png)[Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6300t.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your concern is your iframes are having similar attributes and you have to switch to each one of it before tabing 7 times.

Approach would be
Just like getting all windows handles and then loop you can use common xpath for iframe for e.g

```
   findelements(By.Xpath("//iframes))
```

this will return iframe elements and then you can use loop and traverse and use

> SwitchToFrame().

Answer (score 0):

If your webpage is containing multiple frames and you need to perform an action on each frame too then I suggest trying to create an object for those frames and assign it to the 'document' object and then try to perform the action on each frame.

```
Sub demo()
    
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE, doc1, doc2 As Object
    Dim frame1 As HTMLFrameElement
    Dim frame2 As HTMLFrameElement
   
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   
    IE.Visible = True
    
    URL = "D:\Tests\parent.html"
 
    IE.Navigate URL
  
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
 
    Set frame1 = IE.document.getElementByID("urpopupouter0")
    Set frame2 = IE.document.getElementByID("urpopupinner0")
    Set doc1 = frame1.contentWindow.document
    Set doc2 = frame2.contentWindow.document
    IE.document.getElementByID("btn1").Click
    doc1.getElementByID("btn1").Click
    doc2.getElementByID("btn1").Click
    
    Set IE = Nothing
   
End Sub
```

I tested the above code on my side and it works fine with the multiple frames on a webpage.

Test result:

[image]

VBA code is clicking the button on each frame and on the parent web page which changes the forecolor of the button to red.

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your own requirements.